# crashing out in a while loop python

Tags: python, loops, while-loop

How to solve this error? i want to pass the values from get_robotxya() and get_ballxya()
and use it in a loop but it seems that it will crash after awhile how do i fix this? i want to get the values whithout it crashing out of the while loop

```
import socket
import os,sys
import time
from threading import Thread

HOST = '59.191.193.59'
PORT = 5555

COORDINATES = []

def connect():   
    globals()['client_socket'] = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
    client_socket.connect((HOST,PORT))

def update_coordinates():
    connect()
    screen_width = 0
    screen_height = 0
    while True:
        try:
            client_socket.send("loc\n")
            data = client_socket.recv(8192)
        except:
            connect();
            continue;

        globals()['COORDINATES'] = data.split()

        if(not(COORDINATES[-1] == "eom" and COORDINATES[0] == "start")):
            continue

        if (screen_width != int(COORDINATES[2])):
            screen_width = int(COORDINATES[2])
            screen_height = int(COORDINATES[3])
            return

def get_ballxy():
    update_coordinates()
    ballx = int(COORDINATES[8])
    bally = int(COORDINATES[9])

    return ballx,bally

def get_robotxya():
    update_coordinates()
    robotx = int(COORDINATES[12])
    roboty = int(COORDINATES[13])
    angle = int(COORDINATES[14])
    return robotx,roboty,angle

def print_ballxy(bx,by):

    print bx
    print by

def print_robotxya(rx,ry,a):

    print rx
    print ry
    print a

def activate():

    bx,by = get_ballxy()
    rx,ry,a = get_robotxya()
    print_ballxy(bx,by)
    print_robotxya(rx,ry,a)


Thread(target=update_coordinates).start()
while True:
    activate()
```

this is the error i get:
[image]

Comment: you are making too many connections... you need to close them when you are done with them...

Comment: Fix the formatting please, what you have won't compile. Formatting is stuffed up because you have tabs in your code (see PEP8).

Comment: Never mind, I've modified it to how I think it makes sense, please check and advise

Comment: @paxdiablo if i want to add a last_coordinates = [] which containst the previous values of COORDINATES list. so i could compare both values where should i place this last_coordinates list and how should i instantiate it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you'll find that, because you're continuously creating new connections without closing them down, you'll eventually run out of resources.

That may be a local limitation or it may be the server end getting fed up with too many connections from a single IP.

Regardless, either create one connection and use it over and over, or shut down connections when you're done with them.

---

One possible way of doing this is to `connect()` within the main code before calling `activate()`:

```
connect()
update_coordinates()
while True:
    activate()
```

Then remove the initial `connect()` from the start of the `update_coordinates()` function since that's the bit that does a new connection every time you try to update the coordinates.

If the session goes down for some reason, the `except` bit will re-create it and try again.

That should hopefully alleviate your resource problem quite a bit.

Comment: lol i posted the same thing as a comment at the same time :)  good answer ... I think

Comment: @JoranBeasley do you mind showing an example on how to fix this? i have zero knowldge on this connection thing as this is my partners part of the project

Comment: @JoranBeasley will try that out now but wouldnt that close the conenction?

Comment: why not use the same socket everytime you update the coordinates?

Comment: @JoranBeasley it got even worst socket.error: [Errno 9] Bad file descriptor

Comment: @Edward, is `update_coords()` a separate thread that runs continously? If so, you probably shouldn't be calling it from those two functions. Especially since it never seems to return. Although that could be a formatting problem, since the code as formatted will not compile. Please fix the formatting (get rid of tabs).

Comment: @JustinPeel how do i do that?